# Подсветка внешнего включа в pgadmin в табличном виде

Tags: pgadmin

Есть табличный вид, с которым все знакомы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть ERD

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ERD видны внешние ключи, а в табличном виде у меня на одной машине видны, а на другой(теущей,картинка 1) не видны, виден только первичный ключ. Как включить аналогичную подсказку,как у первичного ключа[PK] на картинке 1, но для внешних ключей